# after refreshing only i am getting the last inserted item

Tags: codeigniter

When i am inserting new manufacturer ,

('already exists ' checking is happening but 
after refreshing only i am getting the latest view.but last insert manufacture is getting after  the refresh.what will i do>

Controller Erp_c

```
function manufacturertable($user)
            {


                     $m1=$this->input->post('man');

          $result['query']=$this->erp_m->insertmanu($m1,$user);
          $result['query2']=$this->erp_m->getmanu();

              if(($result['query'])>0)
              {

                  ?>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        alert("Name already Exists")



    </script>
    <?php
    //              echo"already exists";
    //             $this->load->view('head1');    
    //        $this->load->view('header3');
    //   $this->load->view('manuview1',$result);
              }else{
                  ?>
                 <script type=text/javascript>
        alert("Name Available")



    </script>
    <?php
              $this->erp_m->insertmanu2($m1,$user);

              }

                $this->load->view('head1');    
            $this->load->view('header3');
       $this->load->view('manuview1',$result);
```

model erp_m

```
function insertmanu($m1,$user)
      {
           $this->db->where('manufacture',$m1);
           $res=$this->db->get('manufacturer3');

            $num=$res->num_rows();


          return $num;

      }
```

Comment: in your model, your `insert_manu()` function is missing the insert function `$this->db->insert()`  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data

Comment: you need to show us all your model functions: `getmanu();` , `insertmanu2($m1,$user)`

Comment: also, please try to provide more information. Its very hard to understand what youre asking

Comment: your question is not in sense. please expand your queries.

Answer (score 0):

your information not enough to solve. 
advise : for check available may be you can relocate your code to model, and send return in array.

```
function insertmanu($m1,$user)
  {
       $this->db->where('manufacture',$m1);
       $res=$this->db->get('manufacturer3');
       $num=$res->num_rows();
       if($num > 0 ){
       // todo something
       return array("status"=>1,'msg'=>'name available');
       }else{
       //todo something
       return array("status"=>0,'msg'=>'name unique');
       }

  }
```